# Elementary Set Theory - Questions from final exam, check my answers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Yesterday I had my final exam in set theory, while I think it went pretty well, I'd like to doublecheck my answers, just so I could sleep at night.

Would greatly appreciate any input.

**Question**

1. Find the cardinality of the following sets:

   - a) the set of all sequences of natural numbers.
   - b) the set of all monotonic ascending sequences of natural numbers
2. For every set $A$ of real numbers, we define the subtraction set as: $\bar A=\{x-y\mid \forall x \in A \forall y \in A\}$
   Find the cardinal of the following sets:

   - a) $\{A \in P(\mathbb Z)\mid \bar A \subseteq (-1,1)\}$
   - b) $\{A \in P(\mathbb R)\mid \bar A =\{-1,0,1\}\}$
   - c) $\{A \in P(\mathbb R)\mid \bar A \subseteq (-1,1)\}$

My answers:

1.a - $c$

1.b - $c$

2.a - $\aleph_0$

2.b - $c$

2.c - $2^c$

Can also share my reasoning for said answers, but I just want to check if my answers are correct, rather than bore everyone with the details :)

Comment: It looks fine. You should post your full answers into a single answer to get more feedback, then you can accept it too. (The only thing which is not immediate for me is 2.b, but it seems like the right answer.)

Comment: The definition of $\overline{A}$ doesn't really make sense. Do you mean $\{x-y \mid x,y \in A\}$?

Comment: Reasoning behind 2.b: choose a number $k \in \mathbb R$ and add it to $A$. now look at what other numbers we can add to the set $A$...it can only be $A=\{k,k+1\}$ or $A=\{k,k-1\}$. As any other combination wont yield the proper $\bar A$. You have $c$ options to choose $k$ from.